# Qt C++ QTimer does not call handler

Tags: c++, qt

I've got problem with QTimer in Qt C++, in my code timeoutHandler() is not called. Can anyone tell me why and how I can fix it?

Test.h

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    static bool timeOuted;
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Test();
public slots:
    static void handleTimeout();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
void Test::run()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(handleTimeout()));
    while(!timeOuted);
    if(timeOuted)
    {
        timeOuted = false;
    }
    else
    {
       /* some work */
    }
}

bool Test::timeOuted = false;

void Test::handleTimeout()
{
    static int i = 0;
    timeOuted = true;
    qDebug() << "TimeOuted " << i++;
}
```

Comment: Try making your handleTimeout nonstatic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QTimer` requires Qt event loop to work. When you enter the `while(!timeOuted);`, you block the current thread endlessly and the Qt's event loop has no chance to take any action (like calling your handler for the timer). Here's how you should do it:

Test.h:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Test();

    void run(); // <-- you missed this
private slots: // <-- no need to make this slot public
    void handleTimeout(); // <-- why would you make it static?!
};
```

Test.cpp:

```
void Test::run()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(handleTimeout()));
}

void Test::handleTimeout()
{
    static int i = 0;
    qDebug() << "TimeOuted " << i++;

    /* some work */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update answer from [Googie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2792256/googie) you can use also lambda from C++11:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10000, [=]() {
            // Handle timeout here
});
```